# Get Image from File Storage [Backendless]

Tags: backendless

My users upload some images to the FileStorage at Backendless.
This is the upload sequence:

```
    Backendless.Files.Android.upload(image1_scaled, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
100, "profileImage", "images", new AsyncCallback<BackendlessFile>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleResponse(BackendlessFile response) {
                                fileMapping.profile_url = response.getFileURL();
                                Backendless.Data.of(FileMapping.class).save(fileMapping, 
                                new AsyncCallback<FileMapping>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handleResponse(FileMapping response) {
                                                toast_error("Image stored");
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                                                System.out.println("ERROR" + fault.getCode());
                                        }
                                });
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                        }
                });
```

And that works flawlessly. Now I need to fetch back the image with the API to display it.

So I need to make a `BackendlessCollection<FileMapping> userFiles = Backendless.Data.of(FileMapping.class)`  call to receive the URL back from that table. And then supposedly do a httpRequest with the url to get back the byte data. 
What I can't work out is what sort of **.find** method to use? Do I **.findById()** ? And if so, what ID do I use? The "path", "name" ,"table" etc?

Could anyone show an example fitting my case here, with a table storing the url's and such?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd this something like this (showing sync call for simplicity, but make sure to change it to Async on Android):

```
BackendlessCollection<FileMapping> fileMappings;
fileMappings = Backendless.Data.of( FileMapping.class ).find();
Iterator<FileMapping> iterator = fileMappings.getCurrentPage().iterator();

while( iterator.hasNext() )
{
  FileMapping fileMapping = iterator.next();
  Log.i( "MyApp", "file URL is " + fileMapping.profile_url );
}
```

Comment: AsyncCallback on the .find call? Cause I keep getting "Incompatible Types" from it. It requires a BackendlessCollection<FileMapping> but finds "void"?

Comment: @Benni Sync method returns BackendlessCollection, but async one returns void, as it get the result into callback.

Comment: @Scadge I'm with you that far. But it got confusing when my FileMapping class got involved . Would you be kind enough to supply an example using the Async method in my case? Otherwise I'll just end up guessing around in my code.

Comment: For the Mark's example above it'll be:
Backendless.Data.of( FileMapping.class ).find(new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<FileMapping>() {
@Overridde
public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<FileMapping> fileMappings) {
//do operations
}));
Sorry for one-liner - not allowed to markdown in comments. Don't you use IDE? it would suggest you a refactoring